# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, machine-learning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ1as.png)
This is my code. When the string length of each attribute is equal to 1 and the string is '0', I want to execute the string `replace` function. The code block is below:

```
while ((data['Minutes'].str.len()) == 1):
    if (data['Minutes']=='0'):
        data["Minutes"]= data["Minutes"].str.replace("0", "00", case = False)
    else:
        data["Minutes"]=data["Minutes"]
```

but i get an error :

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The link below is the col I am working on, I have filled the `NaN` with `0`.
Then i combine it with my `hrs` col. Then I convert the new col into `datetime` datatype.

Ex: My third row will be displayed as 19:0... but when I convert it into `datetime` datatype I am facing an issue. Hence I want to get 19:00. I was trying to achieve it using the above code.

Pardon me for my poor explaining skills. I am new to both python and machine learning. This is my first stackoverflow post. I will try to me more clear from now.

Comment: What type is `data`? What does your question have to do with machine learning? Please take the [tour] and read [ask]!

Comment: Please include the complete traceback and a bit more code in your question

Comment: This makes little sense. You need to follow some tutorials on Pandas; you're basically saying `while [True, False, True]:`

Comment: I'm almost sure this an XY problem.

Comment: i am extremely sorry guys for the trouble.I am new to this platform and i am trying to learn . I have changed my post , I have added an image of the col i am working on . I have also tried to explain the output i am trying to seek. Thanks for getting back .

Comment: Images of code? Just no. Use text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is much simplier. Just do instead of all your code:

```
data.loc[data['Minutes'] == '0', 'Minutes'] = '00'
```

Which means in plain English: Put the value '00' in cells where the current row-value of the column 'Minutes' is '0' and the column is 'Minutes'